# swift code Euler p1 need help understanding

Tags: swift

can someone help explain this section of code? I'm working through the Euler problems daily using different ways that I've found on the internet and this one has me stumped.

I don't quite understand why "let range" is needed and what it does... nor {variable} in... I think I can work the rest out with some research but these two parts of the below are completely confusing me.

```
let range = 1...9
let anser = Array(1...9).filter {
    num in
    return ((num % 3 == 0) || (num % 5 == 0))
}.reduce(0) {
    x, y in
    return x + y
}

print(anser)
```

Comment: Range isn't used. And it's not "{variable}", it's a closure call (closure for `filter()`, closure for `reduce()`). It's chaining method.
Insted do `let array = Array(1...0); let filtered = array.filter{ ...}; let reduced = filtered.reduce(0){...} let anser = reduce`, and print intermediary variables.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like range is not being used.

When the method filter is called it uses a closure. This closure is a method that has a particular "shape", which is

```
func filter(_ isIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Element]
```

What you see in that code is a shortcut syntax that lets you specify the Element argument.

So, `filter` will take each value in the range 1 to 9 and pass it to the filter closure where it will test if it's exactly divisible by 3 or 5.

The longer way of writing this would be:

```
func f(num: Int) -> Bool {

    return (num % 3 == 0) || (num % 5 == 0)
}

(1...9).filter(f)
```

where `f` is the function we've defined.

The `reduce` part is a little more complex because the `reduce` function takes an initial result and a closure.

```
func reduce<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

The longhand for the complete code looks like

```
func f(num: Int) -> Bool {

    return (num % 3 == 0) || (num % 5 == 0)
}

func r(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {

    return x + y
}

(1...9).filter(f).reduce(0, r)
```

And to have a little fun, we can write it

```
(1...9).filter { ($0 % 3 == 0) || ($0 % 5 == 0) }.reduce(0, { $0 + $1 })
```

Where the $n construct is a reference to the nth argument passed in. You might see this pop up from time to time.

Comment: ok thanks that is really interesting, I will have a play around with this longer way of doing it.  No wonder the range part was confusing me if it wasn't being used!! Thanks again for the quick replies

Comment: NP This was fun to have a look at. I totally recommend using Xcode 10's Playground for this. Xcode will autocomplete a lot of this for you, but it's good to know what it really means. :)

Comment: If you found this answered your question @Sherargh1, marking it as the accepted answer would be nice :)